# Return.portfolio and Return.rebalancing in R

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I want to calculate portfolio returns over time for 10 portfolios. Weights are fixed, i.e. rebalanced every month.

My data (extract) looks as follows (return data, variable name returns_xts)

```
Cash CHF      Cash EUR      Cash USD    Cash JPY     Cash GBP     Cash    SEK    Cash          NOK
2004-01-30 0.0001758268  0.0069666073  0.0143854541  0.02939934  0.039127564 -0.011597439 -0.03418345
2004-02-27 0.0001575201  0.0068025711  0.0045099598 -0.02749282  0.030491352  0.006885383  0.00460446
2004-03-31 0.0002070932 -0.0099222699  0.0041733946  0.05164557 -0.006797264 -0.013120825  0.02877022
2004-04-30 0.0001835614 -0.0011155096  0.0246020555 -0.03410368 -0.009113713  0.013580744  0.02329576
2004-05-31 0.0001878767 -0.0143628583 -0.0323057302 -0.02467392  0.001095043 -0.009360966 -0.01190726
2004-06-30 0.0001861022 -0.0006346109  0.0002228905  0.00000000 -0.006496727 -0.007516115 -0.03100281
```

The structure is:

```
An 'xts' object on 2004-01-30/2013-09-30 containing:
Data: num [1:117, 1:46] 0.000176 0.000158 0.000207 0.000184 0.000188 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr [1:46] "Cash CHF" "Cash EUR" "Cash USD" "Cash JPY" ...
Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
xts Attributes:  
NULL
```

my weights (x) are

```
FI1  FI2 YI1 YI2 BAL1 BAL2 GRO1 GRO2  EQ1  EQ2
1 0.22 0.15 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
2 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
3 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
4 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
5 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
6 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Their structure is

```
num [1:46, 1:10] 0.22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:46] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
..$ : chr [1:10] "FI1" "FI2" "YI1" "YI2" ...
```

So essentially, I want to calculate monthly returns for 117 months for my 10 portfolios.

When I do so with Return.portfolio or Return.rebalancing, I get the following error message

```
Error in checkData(weights, method = "xts") : 
The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names    from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'. 
Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

or

```
Error in Return.portfolio(returns_xts, na.rm = TRUE), coredata(x),  : 
Use Return.rebalancing for multiple weighting periods.  
This function is for portfolios with a single set of weights.
```

My code is as follows:

```
pf_returns=Return.portfolio(returns_xts,coredata(x),wealth.index=FALSE,geometric=TRUE)
```

Can somebody help me out of this misery (ie. help me to restructure my weight matrix)?

Andreas

Answer (score 3):

Your 'weights' object is not a time series.

As stated in the documentation, weights needs to be

```
a time series or single-row matrix/vector containing asset weights, as percentages
```

a single row or vector of weights does not need to be a time series, as it will just be handled as a single set of weights to apply at the beginning of the time series.

If you actually want rebalancing, you need to tell the **Return.rebalancing** function what dates to rebalance the portfolio on, thus the need that weights also be a time series (preferably **xts**) object.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to do this, i.e to make this weight vector a xts time series from 12-87 to 09-13 on a monthly basis?

Comment: You have a weights *list*.  I think your best approach would be to change it into a matrix first, and then into an xts object.

Comment: I also notice that every row of the (non-reproducible) weights object in the question is 0 except for the first row.  If you only want one set of weights, use a vector or a single row time series.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried like this                                                    for (i in 200:310){
    x_ts=merge(as.Date(dates[i]),x)
}
    x_ts=xts(x_ts[,-1],order.by=x_ts[,1])
Dates is the date column, x are the weights in as.matrix format. The reason why you see zeros is that the weight vector is much longer than shown - the weights add up to 100. With this code, only the first date is merged with the weight vector, but not subsequent ones